# UIButton with image losing its newly set image

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uiimage, uibutton

I've got a UIButton (custom, with image) set up in IB which is an IBOutlet in my code.

In my viewDidLoad method in the viewController, I am trying to change the existing image of the UIButton

```
UIImage *newbuttonimage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"newbuttonimage.png"];
testbutton.imageView.image = newbuttonimage;
```

OK, that works when starting the app, but whenever you interact with the button (press it), it changes to the original image (set in IB). There's no other code to change images in the whole project, so what is going on?

Incidentally, when I put the above code in any other part of my project it doesn't change the image.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should try using [`setImage:forState`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/setImage:forState:) instead of assigning the image directly; there are multiple states of a UIButton and, if not set properly, may yield unwanted behaviors (akin to the ones you're seeing).

Answer (score 0):

Doh! I should have used this code instead:

```
UIImage *newbuttonimage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"newbuttonimage.png"];
[testbutton setImage:newbuttonimage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```